# Change image based on time of day

Tags: java

I want to change the image based on the clock. One picture of day and one picture of night. Between the hours of 06:30 to 18:30 is day (shows a picture of daylight). Between the hours of 18:31 to 06:29 is night (shows a picture of the night).

So two images (lets call them day1 and night1) and two time zones.
day1 = 06:30 - 18:30
night1 = 18:31 - 06:29

I'm a newbie when it comes to programming. I want to use this to show my child when it's day and when it's night (or when it's okay to get up in the morning and when it's not).

I guess the best is to use Java. I would have preferred a full screen software. Can someone help?

Comment: You mean JavaScript, not Java. But what have you tried?

Comment: You are talking about using java, yet you have tagged it with javascript and not java. What do you really wanna use? This site is to  find solutions on **concrete** programming problems, not for "how to program this application" or "pls code me this application"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments SO is not about asking someone else to make a program for you, but this just seemed to easy / fun to not give it a go ;)

You could make a java program for this or you could create a very simple web page that does this for you, you could then display this webpage with fullscreen on a tablet or on a computer..

If you want different timezones (Im guessing you want to display it at different places) you could create another page and just edit the time in the javascript.

Fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/4E6Xs/9/

html:

```
<img id="night" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_7-b4ZWNPaD8/TThuPK0cvUI/AAAAAAAAAAQ/jCqRshKkJd4/s1600/night-scene.jpg">
<img id="day" src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Events/Independence%20Day/independence-day-67a.jpg">
```

javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    SetImage();
    window.setInterval(SetImage,1000);
});

function SetImage(){     
    var nowdate = new Date() ;

    var waketime = new Date();     
    waketime.setHours(6);
    waketime.setMinutes(30);

    var bedtime = new Date();     
    bedtime.setHours(18);
    bedtime.setMinutes(30);

    if(waketime < nowdate  && nowdate < bedtime){
         $('#day').show();
         $('#night').hide();
    }else{
         $('#night').show();
         $('#day').hide();
    }
}
```